# Basic Java Calcualtor: Only addition working

Tags: java, math, calculator, operations

I am trying to build a simple calculator that operates on Double values and performs:

+

-

*

/

negation

^2

for some reason, whichever operation i specify when running the program executes the addition function.  So when I try to do

5
7
*

I get 12.0 and not 35.

Any suggestions?

I would also really like some help implementing a way to quit this program when the word "exit" is entered.  I was thinking something like System.exit(0);

but Im not sure how to implement.  this is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Calc {

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    double num1;
    double num2;
    String operation;


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println ("Enter 'exit' to quit the calculator or 'help' for more options");
    System.out.println("Enter the first number:");
    num1 = input.nextInt();


    System.out.println ("Display:" +  num1);

    System.out.println("Enter the second number:");
    num2 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println ("Display:" + num2);

    Scanner op = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Please enter operation:");
    operation = op.next();

    if (operation == "+");
    {
        System.out.println((num1 + num2));
    }
    if  (operation == "-"){
    {
        System.out.println((num1 - num2));
    }

    if (operation == "/"){
    {
        System.out.println((num1 / num2));
    }
    if (operation == "*"){
    {
        System.out.println((num1 * num2));

    }

    }

    }
```

Comment: `operation == "+"` is not how `String` comparison works in Java

Comment: I did that, thank you.  However, the same error persists

Comment: pls accept the ans, if it helps..

Answer (score 5):

there is a semicolon at  `if (operation.equals("+"));`
so, `System.out.println((num1 + num2));` will always work

And also replace, `==` with `.equals("+")`
 as `==` checks for reference, while equals checks for the value of the variable.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.  However now the only operation that returns a value is +.  the others no longer return the + operation, but they just do not return anything

Comment: replace == with equals function everywhere when you compare a string

Comment: please check your open `{` and close `}` its a little bit messy

Comment: operation.equals("-")

Comment: treat each if individually or as elseif..

Comment: if (operation.equals("+"))
    {
        System.out.println((num1 + num2));
    }
    if  (operation.equals("-"))
    {
        System.out.println((num1 - num2));
    }

    if (operation.equals("/"))
    {
        System.out.println((num1 / num2));
    }
    if (operation.equals("*"))
    {
        System.out.println((num1 * num2));

    }

Answer (score 0):

try this way
Instead of using `==` use `.equals()`

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calc {

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    double num1;
    double num2;
    String operation;


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println ("Enter 'exit' to quit the calculator or 'help' for more options");
    System.out.println("Enter the first number:");
    num1 = input.nextInt();


    System.out.println ("Display:" +  num1);

    System.out.println("Enter the second number:");
    num2 = input.nextInt();

    System.out.println ("Display:" + num2);

    Scanner op = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.println("Please enter operation:");
    operation = op.next();

    if (operation.equals("+"))
    {
        System.out.println((num1 + num2));
    }
    if  (operation.equals("-"))
    {
        System.out.println((num1 - num2));
    }

    if (operation.equals("/")){
    {
        System.out.println((num1 / num2));
    }
    if (operation.equals( "*")){
    {
        System.out.println((num1 * num2));

    }

    }

    }
```

Comment: With `if (operation.equals("+"));` in there, it will still not work as expected.

Comment: @MadProgrammer It should work

Comment: @Matthias Unaware of ; present so fixed now

Comment: `if  (operation.equals("-")){ {`...?

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes thats true,well OP has mentioned that only + was working So i did not check line by line.Well == shouldnt be replaced with .equals()?

Comment: Yes, the `String` comparison is fix, but if you're going to dump code back on the user, you should at least make an effort to make it actually work, letting the poor OP know everything else that's about to blow up in there face - IMHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sure I will do it next time .

Answer (score 0):

please change `operation ==` to `operation.equals("your value")`

Comment: I changed all of the == to .equals and the same error persists

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three main issues with your code...

Firstly, `String` comparison in Java is done using `.equals` not `==`

Secondly...

```
if (operation == "+");
```

Has a semi-colon at the end, which basically means that even if the condition is meet, it will not run anything, but will skip to the next execution block, which is ...

```
{
    System.out.println((num1 + num2));
}
```

Thirdly, you have an extra open brace (`{`) here...

```
if  (operation == "-"){
{
```

Here...

```
if (operation == "/"){
{
```

And here...

```
if (operation == "*"){
{
```

Which is going to completely screw up your logic

You should also make use of `else-if` blocks as well...

Instead, try something like...

```
if ("+".equals(operation))//;
{
    System.out.println((num1 + num2));
} 
else if ("-".equals(operation)) //{
{
    System.out.println((num1 - num2));
}
else if ("/".equals(operation)) //{
{
    System.out.println((num1 / num2));
}
else if ("*".equals(operation)) //{
{
    System.out.println((num1 * num2));
}
```

I've commented out the problem areas so you can see where they exists before hand